# Is this job ad supposed to be a joke? (Does Stack Exchange screen job ads before they are posted?)

Tags: discussion, jobs

I stumbled upon the following job ad (now deleted):

- https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/112732/hacker-with-good-logic-and-deep-php-coding-natural-breakthroughs-research?med=clc&ref=large-sidebar-orange-looking

Does anyone read job ads before they are posted?

Comment: So? Why do you think it is a joke? And you would be surprised at how some people really don't know how to write a job post.

Comment: No, I'm not surprised, but this is obviously a joke. I've stumbled upon this add on reddit, not here on SO.

Comment: It isn't obviously a joke in my eyes. Just someone who is completely tone deaf. Again - why do you assume it is a joke?

Comment: They are searching for hacker and sell one of the best herbal testosterone supplements in the world.

Comment: So, isn't that a legal business? @JosipIvic

Comment: So, company which sells herbal testosterone supplements is searching for hacker, and that's not a joke?

Comment: What, they don't need programmers?

Comment: Don't confuse 'Hacker' with 'Cracker'.

Comment: @Oded, sry, but I never saw a job add like this and I think it's a joke.

Comment: I have seen a lot of bad job listings - agree that this one is possibly one of the worst. C'est la vie.

Comment: I find those Crossover ads looking for super specialized experienced engineers at $15 per hour a much bigger joke.

Comment: I find it more of a joke that some corps are looking for people with experience that would easily merit 4-5x the salary that they quote, but alas.

Comment: Why oh WHY didn't you take a snapshot of that ad?  Now we'll never be able to enjoy its awfulness!

Comment: @won't Google has a cached version: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Astackoverflow.com%2Fjobs%2F112732%2Fhacker-with-good-logic-and-deep-php-coding-natural-breakthroughs-research

Comment: @JDB "Hacker With ***Good Logic*** And ***Deep PHP Coding Experience***" HAH!

Comment: @Won't - I have two favorites: **1** "*I need perfect English.  This is no exception.  I need to be able to communicate with you and that you understand both spoken and written English. Alright..*" **2** "*You need to be online most of the day -- and when you are not - still be.*" 24/7/365 availability, perfect English and "*understand what we are doing to so deep level that you can develop your own solutions*" for $12-25k? What kind of masochist is he hoping to get?

Comment: @JDB hey, don't forget the job comes with perks--awesome testosterone supplements.

Comment: @Won't Oh... that explains it. Every week you get 3 little baggies of "testosterone supplements". Sign me up!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let's close \[jobs\] questions!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377689/lets-close-jobs-questions) - There are no more Jobs / Careers at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not a joke.

It is a real listing, an actual client that is looking for programmers.

Agreed - it is a really bad listing, bad enough to look like a joke.

When you see something like this - flag it. It will get reviewed.

---

I was in contact with someone in the team - they said the post got so many flags that they have now taken it down.

Comment: Can companies post such ads without any review? For some reason I thought that like external ads, they have to send it first to SE, and SE employee in the Careers team actually publish them.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - ads are posted without review, AFAIK. The sales reps (and customer success team) will look into them (sometimes before being posted, but usually after). Flags go straight to the customer success team who will deal with them. The post in question was live less than 24 hours.

Comment: Just to add - there are a lot of listings coming up. Gating that by reviews just isn't scalable. That's why we have flagging. External ads, on the other hand - we don't have many, so the process works with people gating them.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. But still, I think that before a job listing become an ad, it better go through some review. Is it worth a feature request in your opinion?

Comment: We don't have the man power and making this a requirement can really hurt the business. We have found that flagging works well - even if the odd one slips through on a rare occasion.

Comment: I would also think that the process involved in posting an ad would make it such that abuse would be difficult, expensive and fruitless.

Answer (score 2):

No. No member of Stack Exchange reads the job ad before the company posts it.

You can flag it though if you think it is inappropriate. Please make clear from your flag why you think it is inappropriate. (And I guess the job ad worked, since you are actually reading it)

Note that you only should flag inappropriate content. In this case, I think the job ad does lack the quality I am used to, but nothing really to flag. Just ignore it.

Comment: No, it didn't worked, au contrair. I laughed because add is gibberish. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Okay, so skip it then.

Comment: ok I'll ignore it.